# QFuture<void> won't work

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qfuture

I am trying to make my application run on multiple threads to make its processes more efficient. I found, on the Qt's website, the [`QFuture`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfuture.html) temmplate class that could help me. I am trying to use like in one of their examples. Below is part of my class declaration/definition.

```
class PreferencesWindow {
public:
    PreferencesWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
public slots:
    void dbsChanged();
}

PreferencesWindow::PreferencesWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) {
    QFuture<void> fns = run(dbsChanged);
}
```

When I try to run it, I get 48 errors (from this single line) like:

```
error C2780: 'QFuture<FunctionObject::result_type> QtConcurrent::run(FunctionObject *,const Arg1 &)' : expects 2 arguments - 1 provided
```

Where am I wrong and how should do this to run that slot on a different thread?

**Why do I want this?**
The execution of this method could take up to 30 seconds (it checks some database settings). During this time the GUI is frozen, and this will lead to a bad user experience, so I find this to be a good solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should provide the pointer to the object and also the address of the class member function like :

```
QFuture<void> fns = QtConcurrent::run(this,&PreferencesWindow::dbsChanged);
```

If your function has parameters you can pass them by :

```
QFuture<void> fns = QtConcurrent::run(this,&PreferencesWindow::dbsChanged, val1, val2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`dbsChanged()` is a member function - you need to provide an object on which to execute it. If you want it on the object itself, use `this`:

```
PreferencesWindow::PreferencesWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) {
    QFuture<void> fns = run(dbsChanged, this);
}
```

Comment: it is a little better. I get only 42 errors now :))